# What is the Hebrew text for this prayer?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, shema

According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord%27s_Prayer#Relation_to_Jewish_prayer) about the Christian "Lord's Prayer,"

> A blessing said by some Jewish communities after the evening Shema includes a phrase quite similar to the opening of the Lord's Prayer: "Our God in heaven, hallow thy name, and establish thy kingdom forever, and rule over us for ever and ever. Amen."

What is the Hebrew text for this phrase?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> אֱלֹהֵינוּ שֶׁבַּשָּׁמַיִם יַחֵד שִׁמְךָ וְקַיֵּם מַלְכוּתְךָ תָּמִיד וּמְלֹךְ עָלֵינוּ לְעוֹלָם וָעֶד
>
> <sup>*Eloheinu shebashamayim yached shim'cha v'kayem malchut'cha tamid um'loch aleinu l'olam va'ed.*</sup>
>
> Our G-d who is in Heaven, unify Your Name and establish Your kingdom always, and rule over us forever and ever.

~From the evening prayers