# Are these passages really found in the Jewish prayers? If so, where can I find the original Hebrew text?

Tags: hebrew, prayer-book

In [this book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Parish_Recollections_a_few_plain_sermons/Nt1oAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22our%20father%20which%20art%20in%20heaven%20thy%20name%20be%20sanctified%20thy%20kingdom%20reign%22&pg=PA4&printsec=frontcover), a Christian writer by the name of John Hutchinson alleges that the following passages are found in the Jewish prayers, and that when collected together, compose a form similar to the Christian "Lord's Prayer"

> Our Father which art in heaven. Thy Name be sanctified. Thy kingdom reign. Do Thy will in heaven. Forgive us our sins. Lead us not into the hand of temptation, and deliver us from Satan. For Thine is the kingdom, and Thou shalt reign gloriously for ever and ever.

I have been unable to confirm that these passages are, in fact, all found in the Jewish prayers. So are they? If so, where can I find the original Hebrew text?

To be clear: I am NOT asking for a Hebrew translation of a Christian prayer. Rather, I am looking to fact check a claim made by a non-Jewish source about the Jewish prayers.

Also, I am looking for the phrases listed above specifically, not vaguely similar sounding ones (like [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90360/what-is-the-hebrew-text-for-this-prayer))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Hebrew text for this prayer?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90360/what-is-the-hebrew-text-for-this-prayer)

Comment: @Kazi bácsi: Not really, since the phrases I'm looking for don't really match the phrase in that question.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to Google "[The Jewish Origins of the Lord's Prayer](https://www.academia.edu/27950201/The_Jewish_Origins_of_the_Lords_Prayer)" by Leo Michel Abrami. It appears well researched and answers your question (in the affirmative).

Comment: Thank you Phil for your answer. Could you please summarize his answer, such as which Jewish prayers this came from?